# Creating an autolayout button group

Tags: xcode, cocoa, autolayout

Okay, so I'm stuck on this problem.
I'm fetching an array of 2-15 titles (NSStrings) which is passed into my custom class TriButtonGroup to be turned into a row/multiple rows of buttons! The group of buttons (subclasses of UIButton) will line up horizontally IF they all can fit! This works JUST FINE as long as all titles fit inside the buttons! But I need the TriButtonGroup to move some of the buttons to a new row if there's a shortage of horizontal space. See the images attached for better detail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my code, right now, it doesn't handle the situation of the string being too long.. I just can't get my head around this! :(

```
int numButtons = [titleArray count];
        int counter = 0;
        TriButtonCell *previousButton = nil;

        for(NSString *title in titleArray) {

            TriButtonCell *button = [[TriButtonCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
            [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTag:1250+counter];
            [button addTarget:nil action:@selector(pushButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
            [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            [self addSubview:button];

            //Add the correct sizing!
            if(previousButton != nil) {
                [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
                [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
            } else {
                //This is the first button! Set the correct width!
                [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[button]" options:0 metrics:metricsDictionary views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
            }
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[button(60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];

            previousButton = button;

            counter++;
        }

        //Set the distance to the last button!
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[previousButton]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousButton)]];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of would be asking each `TriButtonCell` for its `intrinsicContentSize` and working out manually which buttons fit on a row, and creating the constraints for each row separately.

Something like this (written off the top of my head, so it might not be 100% accurate)

```
CGFloat rowWidth = 0.0;
NSView *previousButton;

for (NSString *title in titleArray) {
    TriButtonCell *button = [[TriButtonCell alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    // rest of button init here

    NSSize intrinsicSize = [button intrinsicContentSize];

    if(rowWidth + intrinsicSize.width < [self bounds].size.width) {
        if(previousButton != nil) {
            NSDictionary *viewsDict = {@"previousButton":previousButton, @"currentButton": button};
            [self addConstrints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[previousButton][currentButton(==previousButton)" 
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDict];
        } else {
            //This is the first button! Set the correct width!
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[button]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil 
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
        }
    } else {
        // We need a new row.
        rowWidth = 0.0;

        NSDictionary *viewsDict = {@"previousButton":previousButton, @"currentButton": button};
        // Connect the top of the current button to the bottom of the button of the previous row
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousButton][currentButton]"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:viewsDict];

        // Also connect it to the left side of the parent view
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[currentButton]"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:viewsDict];
    }

    previousButton = button;
    counter++;

}

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:"@[previousButton]|"
                options:0
                metrics:nil
                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousButton)]];
```

Comment: Solved it using sort of your answer above :) Sorry for the long wait for accepted answer!